# Typing Indicator in MS Teams From Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I am using Bot framework V4 to Build bot and enabled it in Teams.

I am using this code to Show Typing Indicator from bot :-

```
Activity replyTyping = activity.CreateReply();
  replyTyping.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
  await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(replyTyping);
```

Because of this bot is Showing "My Bot is typing..."
but I want different typing indicators based on users.(want to show different Bot name for different Users)

Can we do that?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps worth asking, out of interest - why do you want the bot to appear as a different bot to each user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Chekrii This is not possible. Each Bot has a unique id and a common name. You cannot specify different names for different users.